# Get Single record for Each Ids in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, laravel-5.4

How to get Single Record (Last Inserted Record) for Selected Ids in Laravel.

My Query :

```
  $familymembers=Membersfamilydetails::Where('member_id',$id)->select('id')->get();

    foreach($familymembers as $famil){

    $faids[]=$famil->id;

    }

$familyeducationDatas=Familyeducation::whereIn('familymemberid', $faids)->orderBy('id','DESC')->first();
```

If Family Members Table Return Four Ids, I Need Last Inserted Record for this Four Ids in Family Education Table.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: question not clear?

Comment: $familymembers=Membersfamilydetails::Where('member_id',$id)->select('id')->first()->orderBy('id', 'desc');

Comment: @lan  I want Last Inserted Rows in Family Member Table Selected Ids.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a column

> created_at

which should be the timestamp in Family Education table and re-write the query as follows:

> $familyeducationDatas=Familyeducation::whereIn('familymemberid',
>   $faids)->orderBy('created_at','DESC')->first();

Answer (score 0):

Use `SELECT MAX(id) FROM TABLE`. This will return the highest currently in use primary key for the table.

Comment: Familyeducation::whereIn('familymemberid', $faids)->MAX(id)->get(); is Correct Query.. i am beginer so, pls guide me.. @btl

Comment: MAX is not an eloquent method in this sense, you'll need to use it in a raw query.